# Python- problem with "bpy.data.objects['anyobject'].select=True "

Tags: python, objects, selection-tools

What happens exactly, is that after duplicating an object, then deselecting all selected objects, using:

```
bpy.ops.object.duplicate()
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
```

then running:

```
bpy.data.objects['anyobject'].select=True
```

object is selected in red outline, not orange as usual, as a result, when editing object in edit mode, also in python, it doesn't work either
however, before running `bpy.ops.object.duplicate()`, everything works properly.

I stumbled at this weird problem for a long while, i wonder how to fix it

Comment: Could you please accept and upvote the answer if it was helpful?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set active object with python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78359/set-active-object-with-python)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the object to be the active object as well as selected

The below code works for me, I just added a Cube at origin (0, 0, 0) selected it then run this script from the text editor (or you can run it from the console as well):

```
import bpy
C = bpy.context
scene = C.scene
bpy.ops.object.duplicate()
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.data.objects['Cube'].select=True
scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
```

This is what happens after running the script:

[image]